# Is there a reason to have both a [history] tag and a [food-history] tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

These tags are not broadly used - though this is not exactly unexpected, as we tend to focus on applied cooking than on cooking history.

[food-history](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food-history) has 14 questions and has a tag wiki excerpt

> Questions pertaining to current culinary practices and foods--how did we get where we are today?

[history](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) has 31 questions and no tag wiki.

Can we combine these into one? I don't have a particular care about which is which but I don't really see why we have two.

If the concern of [food-history](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food-history) is that it might relate to foodstuffs only (despite the excerpt), I would recommend that "food" is redundant as this is a site about cooking, so perhaps [history](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) should win out. Alternately, we could replace them both with something more specific than "history" but broader than "food-history" like [culinary-history](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/culinary-history).

Comment: There was one tagged with both! https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34609/looking-for-coffee-from-the-80s-for-my-father-lucern

Comment: Yeah. I edited another one when I asked this... seeing them both on one question was what made me ask in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After posting the answer below, I waited a while heard no objections, and merged into [history](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history).

---

I don't really see any value in trying to subdivide [history](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history). The line between "culinary practices" and "foods" is not at all a clear one, so there's no reason to expect people would intuitively split into [culinary-history](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/culinary-history) and [food-history](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food-history) or anything similar.

I also don't see any need to clarify [history](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history). It pretty clearly means "history of things that are on topic on the site", which is pretty much just culinary things.

Comment: This seems to agree with my thoughts on the subject.